# OData 4.0 WebAPI Asp.Net Core custom navigation Link

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I have working OData Example. The output is as follows.

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44347/api/$metadata#Employees","@odata.count":9,"value": 
[{"Id":1,"FName":"Fnam - 1","LName":"LName - 1 name","Age":1},{"Id":2,"FName":"Fnam - 
2","LName":"LName - 2 name","Age":2},{"Id":3,"FName":"Fnam - 3","LName":"LName - 3 name","Age":3}, 
{"Id":4,"FName":"Fnam - 4","LName":"LName - 4 name","Age":4},{"Id":5,"FName":"Fnam - 5","LName":"LName 
- 5 name","Age":5},{"Id":6,"FName":"Fnam - 6","LName":"LName - 6 name","Age":6},{"Id":7,"FName":"Fnam - 
7","LName":"LName - 7 name","Age":7},{"Id":8,"FName":"Fnam - 8","LName":"LName - 8 name","Age":8}, 
{"Id":9,"FName":"Fnam - 9","LName":"LName - 9 name","Age":9}],"@odata.nextLink":"https://localhost:44347/api/Employees?$filter=Id%20lt%20200&$count=true&$skiptoken=Id-100"}
```

My Url looks like this

```
https://localhost:44347/api/Employees?$filter=Id%20lt%2010&$count=true
```

and my controller is very boilerplate as below.

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(PageSize =100)]
public IQueryable<Employee> Get()
{
    return _valueContext.Employee.AsQueryable();
}
```

I am looking to add navigation links in addition to @odata.NextLink.

How can I Add current request link as @Odata.Self and previous link @Odata.Previous?